# SQLAlchemy: increasing memory on simple query

Tags: python-2.7, sqlalchemy

I am currently playing around with SQLAlchemy a bit, and I found a strange behaviour about memory usage. I'm using sqlalchemy with version 1.1.10 running on python 2.7.13

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals

from contextlib import contextmanager

import memory_profiler
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column, Integer
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

Base = declarative_base()

e = create_engine('mysql://root:root@127.0.0.1:3306/MyDb?charset=utf8')


class Currency(Base):
    __tablename__ = "currency"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

Base.metadata.create_all(e)
Session = sessionmaker(autoflush=True, bind=e)


@contextmanager
def session_scope():
    """Provide a transactional scope around a series of operations."""
    session = Session()
    try:
        yield session
        session.commit()
    except:
        session.rollback()
        raise
    finally:
        session.close()


@memory_profiler.profile(precision=6)
def foo():
    with session_scope() as session2:
        result = session2.query(Currency).filter_by(id=1).first()
        print(result.id)


while True:
    foo()
```

It seems that the memory it's never freed, and that continuously increase. The output of memory_profiler is as follow:

```
Line #    Mem usage    Increment   Line Contents
================================================
    40  53.875000 MiB   0.000000 MiB   @memory_profiler.profile(precision=6)
    41                             def foo():
    42  53.875000 MiB   0.000000 MiB       with session_scope() as session2:
    43  53.886719 MiB   0.011719 MiB           result = session2.query(Currency).filter_by(id=1).first()
    44  53.886719 MiB   0.000000 MiB           print(result.id)

Line #    Mem usage    Increment   Line Contents
================================================
    40  53.953125 MiB   0.000000 MiB   @memory_profiler.profile(precision=6)
    41                             def foo():
    42  53.953125 MiB   0.000000 MiB       with session_scope() as session2:
    43  53.957031 MiB   0.003906 MiB           result = session2.query(Currency).filter_by(id=1).first()
    44  53.957031 MiB   0.000000 MiB           print(result.id)
```

Is there a way to solve this problem? I've tried with session.expunge_all() but it seem not working as expected. Or is there a problem with my code?

Comment: it's probably a side effect of @memory_profiler. Try using a more fine-grained tool like https://pythonhosted.org/Pympler/

Comment: also that's only two iterations, what happens over 200 iterations, constantly increases?

Comment: it's not a side effect of memory_profiler, I tried to remove and still the same problem...these two are only two examples, the memory continues to increase

Comment: are you using a very old MySQL-Python?    upgrade to the latest mysqlclient or use pymysql.

Comment: Same problem, even with the latest version

Comment: post a bug report with a **COMPLETE** [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (e.g. includes data delivered via session.add(), etc.) on the bug tracker at https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/sqlalchemy.   the (**single file, no third party imports or packages**) script has to illustrate memory growing when I watch it via top.  Also include complete information about DB version, drivers, OS, SQLA C extensions or not, Python version.  thanks!

Comment: ok, I post a bug report! Thanks